# Why are both gnome-software and the update-manager installed on 16.04?

Tags: updates, update-manager, 16.04, gnome-software

On 16.04 I have found that both `gnome-software` and the `update-manager` are installed by default, why is this so if `gnome-software` is able to carry out the same functionality as the `update-manager` (updating software that is)? Isn't it bad to have two software updaters installed, won't they conflict with each other at all? This does seem a bit strange to me, are there plans in maybe later releases for the `gnome-software` application to completely replace the `update-manager` or is it just going to stay like this for ever with two applications installed that can do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `gnome-software` application can only handle app upgrades, not core system upgrades such as kernel upgrades, so the `update-manager` is needed for that.

Though this is likely to be a work in progress as on Fedora they have already managed to get the `gnome-software` application to handle core system upgrades, but they have a different backend to Ubuntu so it may take some time before the `gnome-software` application fully replaces the `update-manager`.